# MATLAB parfor index exceeds the number of array elements

Tags: matlab, parfor

Why MATLAB throws an error even if it shouldn't go to the first case of the switch statement? Below is the minimal example:

```
mycase = 2;
non_crack_bytes = 1:6000;
syn_crack_bytes = 1:10000;
imgCount = 10000;
parfor j = 1 : imgCount
    switch mycase
        case 1
            if ~(non_crack_bytes(j) == 0)
                % Do something
            else
                continue;
            end
        case 2
            if ~(syn_crack_bytes(j) == 0)
                % Do something
            else
                continue;
            end
    end        
end
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Error using ScratchPaperFile>(parfor supply)
Index exceeds the number of array elements (6000).
Error in ScratchPaperFile (line 10)
parfor j = 1 : imgCount
```

Comment: My best guess is that Matlab tries to be smart on parfor-entry and does some loop heuristic, which is erronous in this case. When you change to 10.000 this works as expected and the error also happens on loop entry.
Blame them for no proper debugging messages or inspection tools.

Comment: @Jay-Pi: This has nothing to do with smarts. MATLAB needs to divide up the data arrays across instances. Examining the code inside the loop, it sees that two arrays are indexed with `j`, so it needs to divide up those two arrays. But one of them is not large enough, so it errors out. If it were smarter, it would notice that `mycase` is constant and one branch of the switch is never entered, and it would optimize that branch away before dividing up arrays.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Matlab not returning a helpful message does not help either. The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parfor.html) does not describe the dividing of the arrays or did I miss out anything?

Comment: @Jay-Pi: your documentation page links to this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/troubleshoot-variables-in-parfor-loops.html#bvjfik_

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks. Its abit weird that the requirements are not on the first page though.

Answer (score 7):

@David's answer shows a valid workaround, but the reason it works is not quite all that it seems.

To run a `parfor` loop, MATLAB analyses each variable used within the loop and [classifies them](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/classification-of-variables-in-parfor-loops.html). In the original code, `non_crack_bytes` is classified as a "sliced input" variable - in other words, MATLAB considers that each iteration of the loop needs a single value from `non_crack_bytes` corresponding to the loop index `j`. The error occurs long before the worker tries to read from `non_crack_bytes` - the error occurs on the client trying to send the elements of `non_crack_bytes` that it thinks the worker will need. (This is why the error mentions "parfor supply", a bit of internal jargon relating to sending sliced loop inputs).

@David's fix introduces an additional access of `non_crack_bytes` inside the loop which changes it from a "sliced input" variable to a "broadcast" variable. That means that the client sends the whole of `non_crack_bytes` to each worker. This is why the error doesn't occur, not the careful indexing. In fact, you can just as well fix the loop like this:

```
parfor j = 1:imgCount
    size(non_crack_bytes); % access whole of non_crack_bytes
    switch mycase
        case 1
            if non_crack_bytes(j) ~= 0
        ... % etc.
```

It's the access of the whole of `non_crack_bytes` that forces the analysis to consider it to be a "broadcast" variable, and it's that that prevents the error.

Comment: Interesting. This exposes the inefficiency of “commenting out code” by using a switch statement: you’re sending unused data to worker nodes. Better to use actual comment syntax for that then.

Answer (score 3):

@Jay-Pi identified the issue in their comment. Matlab is careful with `parfor` loops, so here you need to make it more explicit that nothing bad can happen.

```
mycase = 2;
non_crack_bytes = 1:6000;
syn_crack_bytes = 1:10000;
imgCount = 10000;
parfor j = 1 : imgCount
    switch mycase
        case 1
            if j<=numel(non_crack_bytes) & ~(non_crack_bytes(j) == 0)
                % Do something
            else
                continue;
            end
        case 2
            if ~(syn_crack_bytes(j) == 0)
                % Do something
            else
                continue;
            end
    end
end
```